# Is there a term for a "punctuating" music?

Tags: soundtrack, terminology

I'm looking for a term to designate this small piece of soundtrack in some TV shows that can, for example:

- be used as a "punctuation mark" at the end of a scene
- when we see, for a few seconds, the building were the characters will be located in the next scene

I think soundtrack is too general, and there might be another word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm thinking [Sting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sting_(musical_phrase)) or "Stinger" is maybe what you're looking for.

The wiki article has links to related terms such as "Bumper", but I think the definition of "Sting" is closest.

In practice, there is some overlap also with ["Leitmotif"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leitmotif), in the way that a theme associated with a character or place may be used as a fill to suggest a transition - but that is a "Leitmotif" used as a fill or "sting".